# My laravel controller exist but not exist

Tags: laravel

Im using laravel in version 8.2.0

In uploadSite I have form which upload image.
After send form data im getting:

```
Illuminate\ Contracts\ Container \BindingResolutionException
Target class [MainController] does not exist.
```

Command php artisan route:list
Return:

```
ReflectionException 

  Class "MainController" does not exist
```

But command php artisan make:controller MainController
Return:
ERROR  Controller already exists.

My MainController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Main;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

My web.php:

```
Route::post('/upload-main', 'MainController@upload')->name('upload.main');
```

I've tried:

```
Route::post('/uploadMain', 'uploadMainController@upload')->name('upload.main');
```

Delete and create MainController

Comment: `MainController` or `MemeController`? Or both?

Comment: MainController everywere

Comment: Try using the [full class path in the array structure](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files): `Route::post('/upload-main', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'upload'])->name('upload.main');`

Comment: Or `use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;` as mentioned in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files)

Comment: You probably need to import the driver correctly in the path file

Comment: If your `MainController` is really created in `app/Http/Controllers/` you won't see `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller`; try `composer dump-autoload`